# How to add elements in cytoscape graph from react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js

I am trying to develop a project that uses Cytoscape using React Component. I tried to follow the documentation from - https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs and tried to access the `cy` object to use the Cytoscape API.
This is the code I wrote,

```
import CytoscapeComponent from "react-cytoscapejs";

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([
    { data: { id: "a" } },
    { data: { id: "b" } },
    { data: { id: "c" } },
    { data: { id: "d" } },
    { data: { id: "e" } },
    { data: { id: "f" } },
    // edges
    {
      data: {
        id: "ab",
        source: "a",
        target: "b",
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "cd",
        source: "c",
        target: "d",
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "ef",
        source: "e",
        target: "f",
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "ac",
        source: "a",
        target: "c",
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "be",
        source: "b",
        target: "e",
      },
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={()=>setElements(...elements,[{ data: { id: "x" } },])}>Add</button>
      <CytoscapeComponent
        cy={(cy) => {
          cy.add(elements);
          console.log(cy);
        }}
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
      />
      ;
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This creates the graph but when I click on the Add button, then the screen becomes blank. On inspecting the console, I get `cytoscape.cjs.js:831 Uncaught Error: Can not create second element with ID a`

Comment: The message is clear. Don't call set elements twice. Also, do NOT make function calls inside JSX segments. Just call them properly inside JS part. It makes codes hectic and cryptic

Answer (score 1):

You got the state updating function wrong.
Try this,

```
<button onClick={()=>setElements(prev => [...prev, { data: { id: 'x' } }])>Add</button>
```